# Resize Label automatically with the text content in LibGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx, gui

In LibGDX, I want to add some long text content to several Labels. I'm creating those labels in a loop, and the text content is different in each iteration. I want the `Label` to have a size that fits the text exactly. Is there a way to do this? I did `setWrap(true)` to the Label.

For reference, consider a Label:

```
+------------------+
|                  |
+------------------+
```

One copy of that may be:

```
+------------------------------------+
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,        |
| consectetur adipiscing elit.       |
| Nec vero alia sunt quaerenda       |
| contra Carneadeam illam sententiam.|
+------------------------------------+
```

Another one should resize to the content:

```
+------------------------------------+
| Uterque enim summo bono fruitur,   |
| id est voluptate. Illud non        |
| continuo, ut aeque incontentae.    |
| Occultum facinus esse potuerit,    |
| gaudebit; Multoque hoc melius nos  |
| veriusque quam Stoici. Id Sextilius|
| factum negabat. Ita nemo beato     |
| beatior.                           |
+------------------------------------+
```

---

**EDIT:**

Please note that the horizontal wrapping is working perfectly. I need the Label size to adjust with the text content vertically. Width is fixed. Height is not.

Comment: It should do this automatically (does for me). Can you show us how you create the labels?

Answer (score 0):

this may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it might help. I made this function which replace the closest space from the middle of the string by a space line. There is no much to adapt for multi line

It produces this :

```
+--------------------------+
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet|
+--------------------------+

+--------------+
|Lorem ipsum   |
|dolor sit amet|
+--------------+
```

The code :

```
public cutAtMiddle()
{
    // Init values needed for the function
    int delta = getText().length; // This need to be high as possible
    int computedDelta; // We declare here so we don't have to do it in the for loop
    int charIndexToReplace = 0; // The char index to replace by the space line

    // Search for the best index to replace
    for (int i = 0; i < label.getText().length; i++)
    {
        // If char is a space
        if (getText().chars[i] == ' ')
        {
            // Compute distance from the middle of the string
            computedDelta = Math.abs(getText().length / 2 - i);

            // If less than current delta : keep in mind index
            if (computedDelta < delta)
            {
                delta = computedDelta;
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }

    // Replace space by space line
    getText().chars[index] = '\n';
}
```

Then i use it like this :

```
if (myLabel.getWidth() > maxWidth) 
     myLabel.cutAtMiddle();
```

It's not such difficult to do the same thing line by line and not specifically by the middle. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your time, but may be I wasn't clear enough. The Label is already wrapping horizontally correctly. There's a built-in method `setWrap()` for that. What I'm expecting is the Label size to adjust with the amount of text content vertically.

Comment: If you add space line, your label's height will increase, is that not what you want ?

Comment: If it resizes, yes! I didn't test this yet. Thank you, I'll check and report. In my experience, labels don't automatically resize during runtime.